# Android_core build error

Tags: ros, rosjava-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..

I have a problem building android_core..

Can anyone help me?

This is the error i get..:

```
    -compile:
    [javac] Compiling 40 source files to /home/jeppe/ros_workspace/android_core/android_honeycomb_mr2/bin/classes
    [javac] VisualizationView.java:67: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : constructor FrameTransformTree()
    [javac] location: class org.ros.rosjava_geometry.FrameTransformTree
    [javac]     frameTransformTree = new FrameTransformTree();
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] VisualizationView.java:126: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method setPrefix(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class org.ros.rosjava_geometry.FrameTransformTree
    [javac]       frameTransformTree.setPrefix(tfPrefix);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] Note: VisualizationView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/jeppe/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/jeppe/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:693: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_honeycomb_mr2:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.676 secs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38210/android_core-build-error/) by [BaronJeppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2792/baronjeppe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome to bleeding-edge development! :)

I fixed this by creating a NameResolver - here's a patch for VisualizationView.java.

```
--- a/android_honeycomb_mr2/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/VisualizationView.java   Tue Jul 10 21:48:56 2012 -0500
+++ b/android_honeycomb_mr2/src/org/ros/android/view/visualization/VisualizationView.java   Wed Jul 11 13:54:43 2012 -0500
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
 import org.ros.android.view.visualization.layer.Layer;
 import org.ros.message.MessageListener;
 import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
+import org.ros.namespace.NameResolver;
 import org.ros.node.ConnectedNode;
 import org.ros.node.Node;
 import org.ros.node.NodeMain;
@@ -64,7 +65,7 @@
         requestRender();
       }
     };
-    frameTransformTree = new FrameTransformTree();
+    frameTransformTree = new FrameTransformTree(NameResolver.newRoot());
     camera = new Camera(frameTransformTree);
     renderer = new XYOrthographicRenderer(frameTransformTree, camera);
     layers = Lists.newArrayList();
@@ -123,7 +124,7 @@
   private void startTransformListener() {
     String tfPrefix = connectedNode.getParameterTree().getString("~tf_prefix", "");
     if (!tfPrefix.isEmpty()) {
-      frameTransformTree.setPrefix(tfPrefix);
+      frameTransformTree = new FrameTransformTree(NameResolver.newFromNamespace(tfPrefix));
     }
     Subscriber<tf.tfMessage> tfSubscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber("tf", tf.tfMessage._TYPE);
     tfSubscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<tf.tfMessage>() {
```

After this, my `./gradlew debug` finished without an issue, and I could get my Android apps working again.

---

Originally posted by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) with karma: 218 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0